# Error reported when uploading to Android Playstore

Tags: java, android, firebase, okhttp

I am trying to upload my app on playstore but playstore is giving me error which is related to networking library and its not letting me pass untill I fix it. Here is the stack trace for that :

```
StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/ConscryptEngineSocket;->setUseSessionTickets(Z)V
    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:416)
    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getPublicMethodRecursive(Class.java:2079)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2066)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1693)
    at j.g0.k.e.a(Unknown Source:1)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(Unknown Source:17)
    at d.d.i.d.b(Unknown Source:150)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at d.d.d.f$a.run(Unknown Source:11)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/ConscryptEngineSocket;->setUseSessionTickets(Z)V
    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:416)
    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getPublicMethodRecursive(Class.java:2079)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2066)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1693)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(Unknown Source:17)
    at d.d.i.d.b(Unknown Source:150)
    at d.d.i.e.c(Unknown Source:3)
    at d.d.i.e.run(Unknown Source:23)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at d.d.d.f$a.run(Unknown Source:11)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

My App specifications :

```
minSdkVersion = 19
targetSdkVersion = 30
compileSdkVersion = 30
buildToolsVersion = '28.0.2'
```

Networking library used :

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.1'
```

Please let me know is there any way to resolve this.

Comment: No, this error doesn't let me submit the app. In above answer there is not fix given for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is being returned because your app is trying to use `setUseSessionTickets`, which is not permitted. This was previously used by OkHttp, and is fixed in more recent versions.

This issue is [fixed in version 3.12.9+](https://square.github.io/okhttp/changelog_3x/#version-3129), you need to use that version or newer:

> **Version 3.12.9**
>
> *2020-02-24*
>
> - Fix: Don’t crash on Android 11 due to use of restricted methods. This prevents a crash with the exception, “Expected Android API level
>   21+ but was 29”.

Note that whilst the patch notes don't explicitly mention your issue, they do refer to the restricted methods causing your problem.

Comment: Yeah i tried with okhttp:3.14.9, and the warning got sorted out..